# how to can validate when click button user with js, this my code

Tags: javascript

HTML

```
<p><span>a</span><input type="button" value="Verdadero" id="v" onclick="verdad()"></p>
<p><span>b</span><input type="button" value="Falso" id="f" onclick="verdad()"></p>
```

JavaScript

```
function verdad() {
    var ver = document.getElementById('v');
    var fal = document.getElementById('f');

    if (ver == 'v' || fal == 'f' ) {
        alert('correcto');
        return true;    
    } else {
        alert('falso');
        return false;
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you are asking...

HTML

```
<p><span>a</span><input type="button" value="Verdadero" id="v" onclick="verdad(this)"></p>
<p><span>b</span><input type="button" value="Falso" id="f" onclick="verdad(this)"></p>
```

JavaScript

```
function verdad(elem) {
    var ver = document.getElementById('v');
    var fal = document.getElementById('f');

    if (ver == elem || fal == elem ) {
        alert('correcto');
        return true;    
    } else {
        alert('falso');
        return false;
    }
}
```

...however, it seems you may actually be wanting to know if `Verdadero` or `Falso` is clicked.  If that is the case, this would make more since...

HTML

```
<p><span>a</span><input type="button" value="Verdadero" id="v" onclick="verdad(true)"></p>
<p><span>b</span><input type="button" value="Falso" id="f" onclick="verdad(false)"></p>
```

JavaScript

```
function verdad(val) {
    if (val) {
        alert('correcto');
        return true;    
    } else {
        alert('falso');
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: hey Shawn, thank you very much, I'm learning to program in java script